# What does Butcher say in The Boys when he's about to leave?

Tags: the-boys

In the comics, Butcher often says something like

> Time to fuck off, Hughie

when he means that it's time for them to go. But this does sound kind of off. I do remember that Butcher definitely uses "fuck", but can't remember the whole phrase correctly.

Comment: I'm up to #74 in the comics and Butcher hasn't said that once.

Comment: @Valorum I kinda starting to think that it was "off we go", which I don't remember that well since I read it a while ago, but 70% sure it's that

Comment: I finished the comics (and all the spin-offs) and I can't really a single time he says that.